# How to grep a string in a program?

Tags: c, linux, io, grep, pipe

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo(char *str_buf_to_grep)
{
    // How to write the following line correctly?
    return system("??? str_buf_to_grep ??? | grep mykeyword"); 
}
```

Description:

1. The `str_buf_to_grep` is given in any way, which might be the content of a text file, and might be very long and complex, even contains special characters, such as `|`, `"`, etc.
2. I want to use the `grep` command to find matched lines, and the patterns might be very complex.

How should I implement it?

Comment: No it isn't obvious. The string to grep is what follows grep, i.e. mykeyword.

Comment: What do you mean by grep? Build a string? Concatenate ?

Comment: Why would use use grep to begin with.  Why not do it yourself with `strstr()` or any other [C style string comparisons](http://cpp-tutorial.cpp4u.com/C_style_string_functions.html)... ?

Comment: @Malina, I revised the question.

Comment: @pedwards, my search pattern might be very complex, here is just a simplified example.

Comment: Rephrase your question then...   ask the complex search question.  You should probably consider the scenario where you want to run without the presence of grep.

Comment: Its legitimate to ask how to stream data to a subprogram easily. The design choice of using grep might make sense in some cases. Grep does a lot more then just scan for for substrings.

Comment: `grep` looks for regexps by default, you'll need to add the `-F` option to search for strings if that;s really what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use popen:

```
FILE* file = popen( "grep mykeyword", "r" );
fwrite( str_to_grep, 1, strlen( str_to_grep ), file );
pclose( file );
```

The echo example by Matt might not work as expected if the string has quotes or similar character interpreted specially by the shell.

I assume your example with grep is just for purposes of asking the question - because like Matt said, it would in all ways be better and faster to look for substrings yourself with a strstr loop or similar.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, what you are looking for is this:

```
char cmd[1024];
sprintf(cmd, "echo '%s' | grep mykeyword", str_to_grep);
return system(cmd);
```

This won't work if your `str_to_grep` includes single quotes (') in it. You would need to replace single quotes with slash+quote (\') in order to avoid shell interpolation.

However, I can't understand why would you want to shell out to `grep` command, rather than use `strstr()` function, like this:

```
strstr(str_to_grep, "mykeyword");
```

The latter is always more efficient, less typing, more portable, and less error prone.

Comment: What if  str_to_grep is very long and complex?

Comment: Do you need to close the pipe afterwards?

Comment: ed: no. System invokes a shell which will clean up any pipes when it exits.